# What is wrong with this description of NAT as it relates to home networks?

Tags: networking, home-networking, nat

I gave the following description of NAT address assignment as it relates to home networks as part of an answer on stackoverflow.
For more details the [full stackoverflow question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788000/ip-address-duplication)

---

...
Your home networks are connected to the internet through a "public IP" (live) address which uniquely identifies yours and your neighbours connections - distinct from other "public IP" addresses/LAN's on the internet.

#### So how do remote machines identify our computers?

This ability is provided because of the NAT (Network address translation) system.

A remote machine (computer) trying to communicate *(update: a remote computer cannot initiate a connection - it can only respond to a connection initiated locally)* with your local computer will send a packet to your homes network's public IP address, your router/firewall will modify the packet so that its intended destination IP address is that of a computer on your home network e.g. `192.168.0.100`
like so:

```
internet ---|
            |
            |--Your (LIVE) IP 211.1.17.23--|
            |                              |
            |                              |--Your computer IP 192.168.1.1    
            |                              |
            |                              |--your other computers 192.168.1.2
            |  
            |
            |--neighbour(LIVE)IP 214.8.12.62--|
            |                                 |--neighbours comp. IP 192.168.1.1 
            |                                 |--other computers IP 192.168.1.2
```

---

The description was immediately downvoted by stackoverflow users and one (high rep) user commented

> NAT has nothing to do with the assignment of addresses

My understanding is that, that is what NAT does, it modifies/mangles the packets so that the packet will request a new IP address, is My understanding wrong, if so how?

Comment: The packet doesn't request a new IP address, the destination IP is "translated" from the public IP to the private LAN IP, which was previously assigned (either statically, or via DHCP).  I assume the reason your answer was downvoted was more that it didn't answer the question, although the content was mostly accurate.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong because you start your explanation with *"A remote machine (computer) trying to communicate with your local computer will send a packet..."*.  The actual message exchange has to start on the client side of the NAT server which are your PCs in the private subnet.

Comment: Fair enough, I get that a 3 way SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK has to occur first before a connection can be established. thanks for pointing out, will update. Regarding NAT, I thought NAT actually rewrote/configured the contents of the packet, so that devices upstream would use the "updated" packet info? Does the router simply redirect the packet unchanged?

Comment: @MichaelColeman, SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK are actually at a higher level (TCP, layer 4), and have nothing to do with NAT.  NAT is taking place at layer 3.  And, yes, it is modifying the packets.  On packets leaving the network, it modifies the SRC IP and makes it the public IP, on incoming packets it rewrites the DEST IP from the public IP to the appropriate LAN IP.